# Which folders to commit when using Github with CMS systems

Tags: wordpress, git, magento

Probably a silly question, but I cannot find any good advice on the internet so far, so hopefully you guys have some good advice. I would like to use GIT for version control and use it to deploy changes to my websites to the server(s). It's easy when I use NodeJS, but a bit more complicated when using a CMS system, to my opinion.

**When I use NodeJS**

When I use NodeJS it's quite easy to have a `node_modules` folder which contains all the external libraries which I will install on deployment. The rest(my own files) will be saved on Github and deployed to my server if changed. Obviously I will not store the node_modules folder on my Github account or send it to my server (node modules will be installed on the server, on deployment). So it's pretty easy to keep those two (third-party an my own files) seperated.

**When I use Wordpress, Magento or something similar**

Now it gets complicated. Mostly because CMS systems like Wordpress have a folder structure like `wp_content/themes/theme_name/`, so your own theme files are more or less entangled with the core structure, instead of separated like NodeJS. And it doesn't seem right to commit all my core files to my Github account as well or send all those core files to my server on every deploy (I would prefer to install them using composer or something, serverside), because I'll never touch the core files, obviously.

So is there any advice? Is there a better whey to handle this? Maybe change a configuration file with the path to my theme folder or something?

Comment: `define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/content');` is your friend - add this into wp-config.php and you can move your wp-content folder outside of WordPress - thus you don't need to commit the whole WordPress core. I would also recommend using composer to bring in WordPress core and plugins etc... but thats a whole different topic :)

Comment: Thanks Simon! Didn't knew it could be that easy. Now I hope Magento has a similar solution, but I'll dig into that. Thanks again.

Comment: I know you can use composer with Magento - not sure how it works with themes. Something I will have to find out. I will write up a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to move your wp-content folder outside of your standard installation. I tend to have a folder called "wp" with the basic WordPress installation in it and a folder called "wp-content" at the same level for my content files. You can then tell WordPress that your content folder is elsewhere with the following:

```
define('WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/content');
```

That goes into wp-content.php which you can also take out of the main WordPress install (and thus add to git) and place at the same level as your folders.

To make things even better consider looking at composer https://getcomposer.org/ and using that to bring in WordPress core and plugins https://wpackagist.org/ is your friend here. This guide got me started on using composer with WordPress and its a good start https://roots.io/using-composer-with-wordpress/ you can pull in your theme from git as well via composer which is great for when you deploy etc... Capistrano for example can run composer on a server :)

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer :) I guess the only struggle will remain the plugins, of which you'll probably not be able to configure them in you development environment, cause it will be hard to keep track of database changes and migrate those to you production environments I guess?

Comment: Do you mean plugins that you write yourself? (as in ones that are not on wpackagist) Database wise it is hard to manage between various environments. I just make sure I duplicate any changes on one environment to the next. And if starting something new always take a fresh copy of the live db to start from. It is pretty easy to make that work in another environment.